# How we add I frame to facebook wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am doing  facebook application.Can I add Iframe to my Facebook wall using graph api?

Comment: not a duplicate, he asks how to add it to the wall, not the facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. It's not doable.

Comment: With the help of another api ,can I do it or not?

Comment: I don't see how. I'm sticking with no.

Comment: I am trying with  Legacy FBML › fb:iframe.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how you could use that on your actual wall. On another tab, yes. On the wall, no.